# How to convert AV to HDMI?

Tags: hdmi

Is there a way to convert HDMI output to Composite AV? Any wire (HDMI to AV)? I want to connect the display to a development board but the display has composite AV ports and the board has HDMI output. I dont want so many wires so I'd like to also cut the cable and manually solder the wires.

Comment: Since there are many commercial products which do just this, the answer is yes. I guess you could try and find out how they do things.

Answer (score 5):

It's not just wires; a cable can't do what you hope for. Since composite AV is an analog and HDMI is digital, you are going to need circuitry.